# GUT decomposition

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, grand-unification

How can we decompose a generic $SU(5)$ irreducible representation as a direct sum of irreducible $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ representations?

Comment: [That's how](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Grand_unification#The_.5C.28SU.285.29.5C.29_model). What is the problem? You should have said: "direct sum" in your question. Do you completely understand all your terms?

Comment: Sorry, for example, if I want to decompose the 70 irreps of SU(5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know how this representation arose out of the fundamental tensoring in the Clebsch decomposition. [Slansky 1981](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf) illustrates this in (3.1)-(3.3) for the antisymmetric **10**.

The **70** and **70'** you brought up correspond to Dynkin indices (2001) and (0004), Γ and antisymmetric-symmetric, respectively, so, as per his Table 30,

$${\mathbf 5} \mapsto (2,1)_3 \oplus (1,3)_{-2}\\  
\mathbf{70} \mapsto (2,1)_3 \oplus (4,1)_3  \oplus (1,3)_{-2}  \oplus (3,3)_{-2}  \oplus (3,\bar 3)_8  \oplus (2,6)_{-7}  \oplus  (2,8)_{3}  \oplus (1,15)_{-2} \\
  \mathbf{70'} \mapsto (5,1)_{-12} \oplus (4,\bar 3)_{-7}  \oplus (3,\bar 6)_{-2}  \oplus (2,\bar{10})_{3}  \oplus (1,  \bar {1  5} ')_8   .       
$$